# unit testing angular directives templateUrl (include requirejs and ng-html2js

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, requirejs, karma-runner

I am working on a not-yet-huge angular app. I have got a problem with karma unit testing. To make a long story short, I am using angular with requirej. My tests run well if I keep my template embedded in my directive. But as this app will be huge, it will not scale. But when I move the template and load it in my directive with `templateUrl`, I can not get rid of one of the following errors (depending on how I modify the conf):

1. (initial error) *"Unexpected request: GET path/to/mytpl.html"*
2. *"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular"*. This error occurs with different config:

   - when I put `{pattern: 'path/to/mytpl.html', included: false}` in my karma.conf and add a requirejs's define `path/to/mytpl.html` in my test file (this is the way I would like that to work).
   - when I put `path/to/mytpl.html` in my karma.conf then all my template return this error (whether I am using ng-html2-js preprocessor or not).
3. *"Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module templates due to:
   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'templates' is not available!"*. I saw that karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor could be use to create a module that will contains all templates, but it never worked.

*NB: I do not use FQN in karma.conf, I use it here to be consistent. I do not think that matters, but I prefer to precise it*

I saw someone putting each `'path/to/mytpl.html': {deps: ['angular']}` in the shim section of their test-main.js. But it does not work for me and that solution will not scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having set aside this problem for a while and use this time to improve my knowledge and to widen my app, I found a solution.

Brief methodology recap: as *karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor* or *karma-html2js-preprocessor* seems to work on some other projects and  as they are referenced in the official doc, I tried many (almost all, I think) possible configuration combinations to run one of them in my test environment. With no success, I came the clue : I have to drop them and find another way.

The solution came from grunt-html2js. By simply adding to grunt configuration the basic set-up and run grunt, it generate a module containing all my templates - maybe, I will split it later in more meaningful modules. But from here, work is almost done. Then I just had to :

1. tell karma to serve the file has other external tools `file: [ {pattern: 'path/to/mytplmodule.js', included: false}, ...]`
2. register the path in my require conf for tests `path: [ 'templates' : 'path/to/mytplmodule', ...]`
3. shim it, still in require conf for tests, to be sure it won't be loaded before angular `shim: [ 'templates' : 'angular', ...]`
4. load this module in my test file `define(['templates',...], function(){...});`
5. retrieve the tested directive's template `beforeEach(module('path/to/mytpl.html'));`
6. add a step in your grunt configuration to make it automatically generated before running tests.

That's all !

There is a drawback with this approach, it requires to retrieve or mock all other directives' templates used in the tested directive. It could be boring as number of directives grows. But I prefer that for now as it is not invasive for the application's code. Maybe later, especially when I will include javascript's compilation in my process, I will move it from test to app too.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what worked for you. Would you happen to have a github repo (or something else) with end-to-end working?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found solution in the following [article](http://engineering.radius.com/post/77677879234/testing-angularjs-in-a-requirejs-environment).
I guess your problem is in wrong karma or requireJS config, in particular base path setup.
In case your directive templateUrl is relative and that url can't be resolved correctly against karma base path or requireJS base path, then you need to work out this issue.

Let's assume your directive has 'app/directive/myDirective.html' value for templateUrl. Then:

1. Check if your html file is properly included into *files* section of karma config, pay attention to *included:false* setting:

   ```
   files: [
       //...
       { pattern: 'path_to_directive/myDirective.html', included: false },
       //...
   ],
   ```

   of course you can use a wild card chars like * or **, but for troubleshooting purposes I would start with a full path value. According to the value of basePath in karma config, *'path_to_directive'* will or won't be the same as path in your app.

   Ex: if karma base path is one level up from you app root, then your 'path_to_directive' = '**some-folder**/app/directive/myDirective.html'
2. Make sure you can get your file from the browser. Go to http://localhost:karma_port/base/path_to_directive/myDirective.html.js

   While doing this test pay attention to:

   - *base* prefix in the url (karma serves all files from that virtual path and adds this prefix to all urls)
   - *'.js'* at the end of your url
3. Once you get file in step 2, you'll see the actual module code, created by html2js preprocessor. It should look something like this:

   ```
   angular.module('module_path/myDirective.html', []).run(function($templateCache) {
       $templateCache.put('module_path/myDirective.html',
       //...
   ```
4. Make sure *module_path* is 'app/directive/'. If not then you have 2 options:

   - module_path has some prefix => simply remove it by adding the following to karma config:

     `ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: { stripPrefix: 'modulePrefix' }`
   - module_path is shorter => add missing part:

     `ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: { prependPrefix: 'missingPart' }`

   Restart karma and make sure *'module_path'* in step 3 is *'app/directive/'*
5. Make sure you have added angular dependency for your template module (check test-main.js which is basically config file for requireJS). Also keep in mind, that value in shim section will be resolved according to baseUrl value in your test-main.js file. For simplicity, I'll assume that requireJS can get the file from 'requirejs_path/myDirective.html' path.

   ```
   shim: {
       //..
       'requirejs_path/myDirective.html': { deps: ['angular'] },
       //..
   }
   ```
6. Make sure you have included your template as a dependency to your test and also don't forget to load the module:

   ```
   define(['requirejs_path/myDirective.html', 'angular-mocks', '...'], function () {

       describe('test suite', function() {
           //...
           beforeEach(module('app/directive/myDirective.html'));
           //...
       });
   });
   ```

I hope by completing these 6 step you'll get a working test. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, maybe it is more clear than my reply.

what do you think about the drawback with this approach as it requires to retrieve or mock all other directives' templates used in the tested directive ?